# Power Query - Table.SelectRows

Tags: powerquery, excel-2016, m

I have two tables/queries in Excel. One table is a Group dimension that lists out each Group along with some metadata about each group. The next table is the fact table that has monthly information for each group. The tables look like this:

Table1

```
GroupName       Location     GroupID   
Even Steven     New York     04952
BillyBobs       Texas        04035
Nunya           California   04859
```

Table2

```
GroupID     Description    SalesVolume
04952       Even Steven    59003
04035       BillyBobs      98390
04859       Nunya          50194
```

For all intents and purposes `GroupName` and `Description` are different names for the same thing (`GroupName` = `Description`)

**What I am trying to do is set things up so that when I filter Table1 on `GroupName`, Table2 will be filtered as well.** So if I filter out Even Steven in Table1, then Table2 will only show BillyBobs and Nunya.

My current Power Query script looks like this (note: I have another table called "Query", that is just an unfiltered `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table`, I'm using this as the source for Table2. Table1 comes from another table in the same DB):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Query"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Month Year", type date}}),
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

I believe that I need to add a step similar to the following example found online, but I cant figure out how to say I only want rows that are visible on the Group table.

```
Table.SelectRows(Sales_Customers, each List.Contains(Query, [CustomerCategoryID]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we need some way for PowerQuery to know whether or not a row has been filtered or not. One approach is to use the `SUBTOTAL` function. Add a new `Subtotal` column to your `Table1` with the following formula:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(104,[@GroupID])=[@GroupID], "Visible", "Hidden")
```

Now merge `Table1` with into `Table2` matching `Table1[GroupName]` and `Table2[Description]`.

[image: Inner Join]

Expand out just the `Subtotal` column and then filter just the Visible rows.

[image: Visible filter]

Comment: That Table.SelectRows didn't work. The inner join kind of works, but I want the user to be able to do the filter on the Excel table itself. The only way that option works is if I go into the Table1 query and manually pre-filter the column as a query step... Appreciate the help though

Comment: If you want the user to be able to dynamically filter tables without any manually refreshing, then PowerQuery is not the right tool.

Comment: Oh I'm planning on having them manually refresh using the "Refresh All" button after they select their filters. I just mean that they can't go into Power Query and edit the query

Comment: OK. Check my edit. I think I have something that will work.